# How to keep correct SUMIFS formula in all cells in a column

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet, google-docs

**The spreadsheet:**

A time sheet spreadsheet for employees to enter their hours per date, then calculate how many hours they entered within a specific pay period.

It's broken into 2 sections. The left part is their actual hours being entered. The right part is the list of pay periods and the total hours for each.

```
Timecard entries              Pay period totals

.C ....  F ....                 O        P          Q
Date    | Hours               Start  |  End    |  Total
Apr 5     3                   Apr 11   Apr 17      0
Apr 7     3                   Apr 18   Apr 24      0
Apr 12     3                  Apr 25   May 1       0
Apr 13     3                  May 1    May 7       0
                              May 8    May 14      0
                              May 15   May 21      0
                              May 22    May 26     0
                              ....
```

**Technical Details:**

Here is my formula for the Q column that totals the hours that are within the given pay period:

```
=SUMIFS(F3:F,C3:C,CONCAT("<=",P3),C3:C,CONCAT(">=", O3))
=SUMIFS(F3:F,C3:C,CONCAT("<=",P4),C3:C,CONCAT(">=", O4))
=SUMIFS(F3:F,C3:C,CONCAT("<=",P5),C3:C,CONCAT(">=", O5))
....etc
```

**The Problem:**

When I try to drag this formula down through the rest of the cells in the column, it doesn't catch the pattern.  **Instead of keeping F3 and C3 as the starting cells, it increases them:**

```
=SUMIFS(F3:F,C3:C,CONCAT("<=",P3),C3:C,CONCAT(">=", O3))
=SUMIFS(F3:F,C3:C,CONCAT("<=",P4),C3:C,CONCAT(">=", O4))
=SUMIFS(F3:F,C3:C,CONCAT("<=",P5),C3:C,CONCAT(">=", O5))
=SUMIFS(F6:F,C6:C,CONCAT("<=",P6),C6:C,CONCAT(">=", O6)) <-- see this one
```

To copy the formula, I highlight the first 3 cells, and drag the bottom-right little-box down to the cells below (fairly standard way to do it I think).

**Question:**

How can I make the formula continue down through all cells CORRECTLY without changing the starting cells that need to stay consistent (C3 and F3).

Comment: Just a matter of knowing the terminology; a search for [excel absolute cell reference](https://www.google.com?q=excel+absolute+cell+reference) would have been all you needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in excel use $ in front of the row AND column reference to lock them so they do not change during a copy.  Compare =A1, =A$1, =$A1 and =$A$1 as test formulas as they are copied.

After 4 years of using spreadsheets someone showed me the toggle of F4 in excel which is such a time saver for me.  Place your cursor beside or in an address reference and press F4 multiple times to see what happens.  Also try highlighting any part of the cell references in a range on either side of the : and try using F4.  You can affect multiple cell references at the same time or only one depending what you highlight.  The above was referring to an address like A1:A13.

Comment: I'm not sure what the F4 did - it seemed inconsistent depending what i had selected, or in my clipboard..etc, but the `$` worked perfectly to lock the numbers.  Thanks!

Comment: In excel, if you have the cursor on a cell address, and you press F4, it will toggle through adding the various $ for row and column.  First press locks both row and column, second locks only 1, third locks only the other 1 and 4th brings you back to where you started.  If your cell reference already has a lock in it, then Excel will start at that point in the list and loop through the list.